# Google Sheets apps script unable to filter empty strings from array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I've only recently been attempting to teach myself scripting for work and am looking for a little help. I'm trying build an array from multiple sheets/tabs in a google spreadsheet with the bellow;

```js
  var fastenerKitSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);           
  var tabs = new Array();
  var fasteners = new Array();
  
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheet.length ; i++) {
    tabs.push( [ sheet[i].getName() ] );
    var data = fastenerKitSpreadsheet.getRange("B3:D50").getValues().filter(String);
  fasteners.push(data);
  }   

  Logger.log(fasteners);
```

a few problems I am having:

- filter(String) does not seem to remove empty strings from the array.
- the logger only seems to show a result in the log if I remove the curly braces"{}"
- I'm not sure how to get it to cycle through each tab and push data onto the end of the fasteners array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
function stackData() {
var output = [];
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(function (sh) {
sh.getRange('B3:D50').getValues().forEach(function (r) {
if(r.toString().replace(/,/g, "")) output.push(r)
})
})
Logger.log(output)
}
```

Comment: That works thank you. For my understanding can you elaborate on the 5th line? Is it converting the array to a string then replacing commas with empty strings ""? wouldn't that interfere with the commas separating existing elements?

Comment: @user12795762: that shouldn't be an issue.